# Сумма записей (count) по разным датам

Tags: sql, postgresql

Дана таблица postgresql:

| name | date |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 2023-01-15 23:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-01-15 23:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-01-19 23:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-01-20 11:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-01-21 13:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-01-21 13:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-01-21 13:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-09-15 13:15:17 |
| 10 | 2023-08-15 23:15:17 |

Используя count можно подсчитать кол-во "name", за определенную дату, например:

```sql
select count(name) as name from table1 
where date between '2023-01-15 00:00:00'
and '2023-01-15 23:59:59'
```

Вывод: 2

Вопрос такой: можно как то одним запросом, подсчитать кол-во name, но за разные даты или месяцы?

Если бы даты и время были одинаковые, то можно было бы просто через group by:

```sql
select count(name) as name,date from table1 
where date between '2023-01-15 00:00:00'
and '2023-08-15 23:59:59'
group by date
```

Но если добавить в таблицу разное время, то подсчитать нормально не получится.

Comment: ```GROUP BY "date" :: DATE```

Answer (score 0):

Можно преобразовать дату в некоторую строку с помощью функции **to_char**, и дальше уже группировать по этой строке.

Например, вот так можно посчитать по датам

```sql
SELECT COUNT(name), to_char("date", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "part"
FROM table1 
GROUP BY part
```

а вот так по месяцам

```sql
SELECT COUNT(name), to_char("date", 'YYYY-MM') AS "part"
FROM table1 
GROUP BY part;
```

Думаю что логика примерно понятна. Дата преобразуется в строку по некотормоу шаблону, а дальше идет группировка.

Пример рабочих запросов: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1b6869/8