# Как посчитать сумму с разбивкой по годам?

Tags: postgresql, оконные-функции

Есть таблица с данными за весь 2022 год и 2023. Нужно посчитать кумулятивную сумму поля, но обязательно с первого числа года! То есть, например, кумулятивная сумма считается с 2022-01-01 по 2022-12-31. А с 2023-01-01 сумма начинается заново

пока пробую преобразовать данную оконную функцию:
`SUM(fact_mln) OVER(ORDER BY date)`

Как можно преобразовать данную оконную функцию или может есть какие-либо решения ещё?

Comment: Вот только что ответил на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1487291/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-count-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc

Comment: добавить в over что то вроде "partition by extract(year from date)"

Comment: RANGE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC()